# Evaluate $\int_\gamma z^ne^{1/z}dz$, where $\gamma$ is the unit circle.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I need to evaluate $\int_\gamma z^ne^{1/z}dz$, where $\gamma$ is the unit circle traveled in the counterclockwise direction.

I'm thinking about writing the function as a Laurent series and then integrating term by term. Is there any better/faster approach?

Comment: That approach is super quick, so why not?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can change variables to $w=1/z$ to turn the integral into
$$ -\int_{-\gamma} \frac{e^{w}}{w^{2+n}} \, dw, $$
(where $-\gamma$ is $\gamma$ traversed in the opposite direction) and then use the Cauchy integral formula (which is basically the same as the Taylor series anyway).

Less sensible suggestion: integrate by parts until you get to $e^w/w$.